# Jquery loop through table rows and get nth child value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, html-table

I am looping though the rows of the table and trying to get the value of first child. But somehow it keeps returning me the value from the first row only

```
    $("#lookupquicksearchBtn").on("click",function(){
        var searchWord = $("#quickSearchTextBox").val();

        $("table tr").each(
          function(){ 
             alert($("td:nth-child(1)").html());             
          });
    });
```

It is always alerting with the value from the first row first column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following code.

```
$('table tr').each(function(i,e){
    alert($(this).find("td:nth-child(1)").html())
})
```

You could use the `i` to get the index.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use current row context here along with find selector:

```
  $("table tr").each(function(){ 
    alert($(this).find("td:nth-child(1)").html());             
  });
```